# Fixed point property for the total space and base space of a principal bundle

Tags: smooth-manifolds, fixed-point-theorems, principal-bundles

Is there  a  principal bundle $P\to X$ such that $P$ has the fixed point property but $X$ does not have? Is there an example of this situation where $P,X$  and the fibers are compact smooth manifolds?(In particular the  group is  a  compact Lie group)?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What specifically do you mean is "the fixed point property"?

Comment: @Mnifldz  A topological space $X$ satisfies "Fix point property" if  for every continuous map $f:X\to X$ there exist a point $x\in X$ with $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group action on $P$ implies no principal bundle can have the fixed point property, unless the fiber (group) $G$ is trivial. If $G$ is not trivial, note that the morphism (group action) induced on $P$ by any non-zero element in $G$ lacks a fixed point.  If $P$, a principal bundle over $X$ has the fixed point property, then $P=X$ . Therefore $X$ has the fixed point property.